# Is there a maps API that will show closest residential locations? (google places?)

Tags: google-maps, maps, yahoo-maps, google-places-api, mapquest

I have a mobile app where I need try and predictably guess which **residential** location the user is standing in front of. (Not businesses)

I see the google places api, but it doesn't look like it does residential?
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches

I tried searching with a lat an long in a neighborhood, and it brought up all sorts of results that were close by, like parks and schools, but not residential.

Am I missing something? Is there something out there that will let me see what homes are close to a lat,long point?

Comment: Here is a good start, but now I need to know if I can do multiple addresses that are close to that point. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Places API probably won't work for you since it's querying a databases of places or businesses, not residential addresses.  You might want to consider reverse geocoding to the closest address from that point on the map instead: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: Yeah, thats what I put in my comment as well. I just wish I could see a list of locations that are close, not just find the closest one.